# Where are variables allocated when referenced within posted Runnables?

Tags: c#, handler, allocation, android-runonuithread

My understanding (though it could be incorrect!) is that in `Method1()`, `myInt` will be allocated on the stack and then deallocated upon returning from the method.

My question is about where `myInt` will be allocated in `Method2()` because the method could be returned from (and thus `myInt` deallocated from the stack) before the `Runnable` posted to the UI thread's `Looper` is executed?  And yet, in testing, the `Runnable` does still seem to be able to reference `myInt`.  Does the compiler automatically move variables referenced within posted `Runnables` to the heap, even if they would ordinarily be allocated on the stack?

```
public void Method1()
{
    int myInt = 0;

    /* Do some operations on myInt */
    myInt = 5;
}

public void Method2()
{
    int myInt = 0;

    RunOnUiThread(() =>
    {
        /* Do some operations on myInt within a Runnable posted to the UI thread's Looper */
        myInt = 5;
    });
}
```

Comment: This may be helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions#capture-of-outer-variables-and-variable-scope-in-lambda-expressions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method2 creates a [**Closure**](https://csharpindepth.com/articles/Closures). As an *implementation detail* (ie: the language designers are free to change this), the compiler makes a closure work by creating a class behind the scenes where the captured value is now a member property, and access to the value is now rewritten as access to the property in an instance of the class.

In other words, there is now a class instance allocated on the heap holding this value.

Again, this is an implementation detail. It's possible (though unlikely) a future revision might do something like allocate an additional stack frame instead of the class instance.